# express POST is returning 404?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm learning express/node/backend and I'm trying to create a to do list. My `POST` isn't working and returns 404.

Here is the EJS file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>To Do</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <header class="flexContainer">
        <h1 class="title main-font center">Get Shit Done</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="subHeader flexContainer">
        <h2 class="todo-title main-font center">To Do's</h2>
      </div>

      <form action="/addtodo" method="POST"> <!-- POST is here -->
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add a To Do" name="Add a To Do" />
        <button type="submit" class="submitButton">Submit</button>
      </form>

      <div class="to-do-list flexContainer">
        <ul class="task-list center" data-lists>
          <li class="todo-name main-font data-todos">
            <i class="fa fa-circle-thin co"></i>
            <span>to do task 1</span>
          </li>
          <li class="todo-name main-font data-todos">
            <i class="fa fa-circle-thin co"></i>
            <span>Grocery</span>
          </li>
          <li class="todo-name main-font data-todos">
            <i class="fa fa-circle-thin co"></i>
            <span>Play</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my server.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const cors = require("cors");
const { request } = require("mongodb");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.use(cors());

const username = "hidden";
const password = "hidden";
const connectionString = `mongodb+srv://${username}:${password}@cluster0.7k2ww.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

MongoClient.connect(connectionString, { useUnifiedTopology: true }).then(
  (client) => {
    console.log("Connected to database");
    const db = client.db("to-do-list");
    const toDoCollection = db.collection("to-dos");

    app.set("view engine", "ejs");
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(express.static("/public"));

    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      toDoCollection
        .find()
        .toArray()
        .then((result) => {
          res.render("index.ejs", { todos: result });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    });

    app.post("/addtodo", (req, res) => { // POST is here.
      console.log("post a to do");
    });

    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
    });
  }
);
```

Could it be my path? I tried `js/addtodo` and other variations but nothing.

[image: Path]

Comment: why you added routes inside db connection block?

Comment: From my testing this is working fine (with the caveat that the `post` handler doesn't terminate as nothing is sent back), perhaps try testing simpler code, without the MongoDB connection and see if this still occurs?

Answer (score -1):

you need to set one more setting in express by adding a single line of code.

```
app.set("views","./views")
```